# Copy files from one folder to another folder within specific date range

Tags: command-line, bash, copy

I am already using below command to copy files from a specific date.

Previously I used this command and it worked well but now it was showing an error:

```
-bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long
```

Commends used:

```
cd /share/new/
cp `find . -type f -newermt '16 july 2018'` /share/test
```

I need to copy all files in the folder "new" from July 20th to today date. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `cp` directly with the output of `find`.

It might passes way many too files in a single step (and that's why you get the error `Argument list too long`).

Use the `-exec` parameter of `find`, which execute the given command passing a every matched file to `cp`, one at a time:

```
cd /share/new/
find . -type f -newermt '16 july 2018' -exec cp {} /share/test \;
```

Comment: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: @Venki if you type `find . -type f -newermt '16 july 2018'` does any results appear? It might be that no files match your query. Pay attention to the last `\;` , too.

Comment: its working :: ""  find . -type f -newermt '16 july 2018' -exec cp {} /share/test/ \; ""   missing "/" after test because test is a directory

Comment: I added quotes to the "{}". This will make sure files with names containing spaces are handled correctly.

Comment: @vanadium find's -exec executes the program directly. It doesn't invoke a shell; `{}` is replaced with the filename as a single argument regardless of quoting (which find never actually sees, anyway).

Comment: You can improve the efficiency of this command (which probably matters if OP is getting "argument list too long") by specifying the destination explicitly with the `-t` switch, rather than by syntax, and making use of `+` which constructs an argument list, ie `find <tests> -exec cp -t /share/test {} +` The argument list is broken as many times as needed to complete without exceeding the limit. This avoids launching `cp` n times where n is the number of files...

Comment: @IanEmnace Thank! Removed the quotes again, not needed indeed!

Comment: @Zanna Excellent pro-tip to indeed vastly increase the efficiency.

Comment: @Zanna thanks for clarifying the use of `+` instead of `;`. I thought `find` would pass _all_ arguments to the command and not "just enough not to trigger the `Argument list too long`".

Answer (score 3):

use `find -exec`:

```
find /share/new/ -type f -newermt '16 july 2018' -exec cp {} /share/test \;
```

Comment: getting same error for your command also
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: I think your missing the `\;` at the end.

Comment: test is a directory i am missing / after test

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the `-exec` action of `find` and the `-t` option of `cp`; I also recommend the `-i` or `-n` options if you don’t want to overwrite identically named files by accident:

```
find ... -exec cp -i -t TARGET -- {} +
```

The other current answers spawn a `cp` child process for every matching file while this answer only spawns as many as necessary based on the total program argument length limit (see below) which will make a big difference once you reach a couple of thousand matches which appears to be your case.

---

From the [`find(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html) manual:

> - `-exec command ;` – Execute command […].  All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of `;` is encountered. The string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command […]. The specified command is run once for each matched file. […]
> - `-exec command {} +` – This  variant of the `-exec` action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files. […]

From the [`cp(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/cp.1.html) manual:

> - `-t`, `--target-directory=DIRECTORY` – copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
> - `-i`, `--interactive` –  prompt before overwrite
> - `-n`, `--no-clobber` – do not overwrite an existing file

Answer (score -1):

You should try this syntax:

```
find /share/new/ -type f -newermt '16 july 2018' -exec cp -R /share/test/ {} \;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `-R` here? Doesn't it recursively copy `/share/test` to all the files found? That seems wrong.

Comment: Well, no. The OP wants to copy a `$source_file` to a `$target_directory`. The command you propose instead _recursively_ copies the `$target_directory` to the `$source_file`. This doesn't make sense. Not only the direction is just the other way round, but also when copying recursively, the target must be a _directory_, not a file. When we run `cp -R /source/directory /target/file` then we get `cp: cannot overwrite non-directory 'target/file' with directory '/source/directory'`.